# Correlation between the English -wise and German -weise suffixes

Tags: english, german, adverbs

The English [meaning](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/-wise) of *-wise* is the following.

```
-wise adverb combining form

Definition of -wise (Entry 5 of 5)
1a : in the manner of
    crabwise fanwise
b : in the position or direction of
    slantwise clockwise
2 : with regard to : in respect of
    dollarwise
```

However, I'm unable to find in any German sources what *-weise* means. But I know the following words:

- *mysteriöserweise* and its synonym,
- *geheimnisvollerweise*
  both meaning in a mysterious way/manner
- *beziehungsweise*
  meaning respectively

From the aspect of etymology, we know that the English version of *-wise* also comes from German. Is it possible that both of these adverbs mean mostly the same?

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "the English version of -wise also comes from German"? "-wise" is cognate with German "-weise", but neither derives from the other, instead they share a common ancestor in Proto-West-Germanic *-wīse

Comment: Exaclty, I meant that the common ancestor is a Germanic branch.

Comment: They’re fairly equivalent, yes. _Weise_ as a noun means ‘way, manner’, and as a suffix it mostly means ‘in a ___ manner’ or ‘in a ___ way’, but is also used just to form adverbs from adjectives, more so than in English, where _-ly_ is productive. Some more common examples include _normalerweise_ ‘normally’, _glücklicherweise_ ‘luckily’, _teilweise_ ‘part(ial)ly’, _möglicherweise_ ‘possibly’, _paarweise_ ‘in pairs’, _stückweise_ ‘by units’, _zeitweise_ ‘at times’, etc.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet tbf, in lots of those instances variants in -wise do exist in English, even if the form in -ly is vastly more common

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet That would make a good answer (maybe with an additional note comparing -ly and -lich).

Comment: They're cognate, and that's the most one can say about them with confidence.

Answer (score 0):

As a noun, it means 'in a manner/ fashion', as a measurement, 'by the' and as a suffix,'-ly'. So they're similar in a way.